# Use Google Maps to make a Tree Structure as in Khanacademy.org

Tags: google-maps

I was just surfing out the site [Khanacademy.org](http://Khanacademy.org), and just seeing their practice session, when i came across [this page](http://www.khanacademy.org/exercisedashboard), Here I saw something odd, they use google maps to create the structure shown below:

[image]

*Now I am wondering that how can they make use of Google Maps to create a course structure tree like this?*

**PS - If you can't see the link to [this page](http://www.khanacademy.org/exercisedashboard) directly, then I think you need to register.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Here's](http://bjk5.com/post/1664635835/constellation-knowledge) how they did it

Answer (score 0):

IMO it's an Googlemaps overlay.